# Calling specific data in an array created with rollup with d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, rollup

I'm currently working on a visualisation of shipping data and I'm trying to create a line graph where the xAxis is 00:00 to 23:59 on a specific day and the yAxis is the amount of ships at a specific minute during that day. I managed to create an array which contains 1440 Objects (one for each minute). Each object in that array looks like the following:

[Object with data at 00:00 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWxg.png)

[Object with data at 00:01 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IbAz.png)

This is the code snippet I use to create said array.

```js
var shipTotal = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Timestamp; 
   })
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
  .rollup(function(d){
    return d3.sum(d, function(g) { 
    return +g.Enen;
  });
})

.entries(data);
```

Later in my code I try to create a line variable where the X is the timestamp in my main dataset and the Y is the *value* in the array I created, which is the amount of ships at that specific minute.

```js
var lijn1 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d){
    return xScale(shipTotal[d.key]);
  })
  .y(function(d, value){
    return yScale(shipTotal[d.value]);
  });
```

I understand that the X is most likely wrong as well but the line in the code has no X nor a Y coordinate. In the web browser console the line shows d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN... times 1440.

Lastly, the code snippet where I append the path.

```js
chartGroup.append("path")
.data([shipTotal])
.attr("class", "lijntje1")
.attr("d", lijn1(shipTotal ))
.attr("stroke", "red")
.attr("fill", "none");
```

If anyone could help me out here, that would be amazing. I can provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: there's lots of stuff missing from the snippets to tell if this is the only problem, but anyways --->

shipTotal will be an array of objects of the form {key: a_key, value: data_for_that_key}, not an object itself. So you can't access shipTotal by a key like "00:01", just by an index: 0-1439 in your case. Happily  `.sortKeys(d3.ascending)` should mean your data is already sorted by the 00:01 type keys, and you already pass shipTotal in to the line function in your last snippet (`.attr("d", lijn1(shipTotal))`), so you shouldn't need to reference shipTotal in the d3.line snippet anyways. Try this:

```
var lijn1 = d3.line()
  // d at this point should be an individual {key: ..., value: ...} element of the shiptotal array
  .x(function(d, i){
    // assuming xScale domain is set on [00:00, 00:01, 00:02 etc] type keys,
    // if it's 0-1439, try xScale(i) instead
    return xScale(d.key); 
  })
  .y(function(d){
    return yScale(d.value);
  });
```